# Nginx sucessfully password protects PHP files, but then prompts you to download them

Tags: php, nginx, .htpasswd

In a [previous question,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37902392/password-protecting-files-in-a-folder-in-nginx-using-htpasswd/37902448) I was trying to password protect my /admin/ and sub-folders directory using Nginx with .htpasswd and regex.

That was done successfully, but now, after password authentication was completed, Nginx prompts to "download" php files, rather than simply loading them.

This doesn't happen when the new location "authentication" block is commented out. For instance, in this code sample, PHP pages load without any issue:

```
    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    #location "~^/admin/.*$" {
    #       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    #       auth_basic "Restricted";
    #       auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
    #}

    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }
```

How can I resolve these (apparently conflicting) location blocks, so the /admin/ section is password protected yet php files still load?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is a fundamental misunderstanding as to [how `nginx` processes a request](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html). Basically, `nginx` chooses one location to process a request.

You want `nginx` to process URIs that begin with `/admin` in a location block that requires `auth_basic`. In addition, URIs that end with `.php` need to be sent to PHP7.

So you need two fastcgi blocks, one to process normal PHP files and one to process restricted PHP files.

There are several forms of [`location` directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location). You have already discovered that the regex locations are ordered and therefore your `location "~^/admin/.*$"` block effectively prevents the `location ~ \.php$` block from seeing any URI beginning with `/admin` and ending with `.php`.

A clean solution would be to use nested location blocks and employ the `^~` modifier which forces a prefix location to take precedence over a regex location:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;

    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
}

location ^~ /admin/ {
    auth_basic "Restricted";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;

    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;

        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }
}
```

Note that `location ^~` is a prefix location and not a regex location.

Note also that the `fastcgi_split_path_info` and `fastcgi_index` directives are not required in a `location ~ \.php$` block.

Comment: Works for me. Are you sure that the page is coming from the server and not a stale copy from the browser's cache. Check the access log.

Comment: You're right, I was in private mode assuming it wouldn't cache there, silly me.  Turned off all caching in about:config and it's working perfectly now.  Thanks for the great solution.