# NGINX password protection not working on Ubuntu 22

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, password-protection

I need to protect /servis directory with a password authentication. So, I created a password file like this:

```
sudo nano /etc/nginx/conf.d/.htpasswd
```

and I save a user credentials

```
myuser:$apr1$Xw/j.............
```

I changed my virtual server definition file

```
sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/inscubator.cz
```

in this way:

```
server {
 listen 80;
 server_name inscubator.cz www.inscubator.cz;
 root /var/www/inscubator.cz;

 index index.html index.htm index.php;

 location / {
     try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
 }

 location ~ \.php$ {
     include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
     fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
  }

 location ~ /\.ht {
     deny all;
 }

 location ~ /\.cfg {
     deny all;
 }

 location /admin {
     auth_basic "Restricted Access!";
     auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/conf.d/.htpasswd;
 }

 location /servis {
     auth_basic "Restricted Access!";
     auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/conf.d/.htpasswd;
 }
}
```

I restarted NGINX and I restarted the server as well. Unfortunately, PHP scripts in both directories ( admin and servis ) are freely accessible. What could be wrong?

Comment: You are not password protecting `location ~ \.php$` which handles **all** PHP scripts. See [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37906031/4862445).

Comment: Works great, thanks!! Put it as answer, I'll mark it as solution.